# How do I refresh an access token from Azure AD using django-rest-framework-social-oauth2?

Tags: python, django, azure, oauth

The [documentation](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) gives an example of how to convert an Azure access_token that the user already has from the login process, but I'm not seeing anything about how to refresh that token. I managed to roll my own using [adal](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python), the Azure AD library for python, but I'm wondering if there's a better way using the tools included in DRF social oauth 2 or other django oauth packages that I'm just not finding. Please advise. Below is the function that refreshes my Azure AD token.

```
def refresh_social_access_token(self, request):
    """
    This function leverages adal 
    https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python
    to refresh an expired access token.

    .acquire_token_with_refresh_token(self, refresh_token, azure_ad_app_key, 
                                      resource, azure_ad_app_secret)
    """
    user_social_auth = request.user.social_auth.filter(user=request.user) \
        .values('provider', 'extra_data')[0]
    context = AuthenticationContext(f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{self.TENANT_ID}')
    token = context.acquire_token_with_refresh_token(
        user_social_auth['extra_data']['refresh_token'],
        SOCIAL_AUTH_AZUREAD_OAUTH2_KEY,
        user_social_auth['extra_data']['resource'],
        client_secret=SOCIAL_AUTH_AZUREAD_OAUTH2_SECRET
    )
    try:
        expiry = convert_iso_to_epoch(token["expiresOn"])
        user_social_auth = request.user.social_auth.get(user=request.user)
        user_social_auth.extra_data['expires_on'] = expiry
        user_social_auth.save()

    except KeyError:
        HttpError('Oauth2 token could not be refreshed as configured.')
```